# How to write regexp to get a paramater from URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help with a regexp to get only the code parameter from this url:

```
URL: code=4%2FsAB_thYuaw3b12R0eLklKlc-qcvNg6f8E8pgvu_02MTTJE0NOcyvXkrTQrB3QK8209wSbIpLDEBrk8vUGYKQ41I&scope=https:.....
```

My Code:

```
getParameterByName(name) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$|)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

this piece of code is returning `

```
4/sAB_thYuaw3b12R0eLklKlc-qcvNg6f8E8pgvu_02MTTJE0NOcyvXkrTQrB3QK8209wSbIpLDEBrk8vUGYKQ41I
```

In this case i need the first and only backslash to be a % sign instead..

I can't get it to work.

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do but if you just want everything between "code="  and the next "&" try "code=([^&]*)"   I assume you have a reason for not doing this, if so, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me!!!

```
function getUrlParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: I like this because you answered it in the format of KENUBBE despite the fact KENUBBE can do this with one regex without using replace or any other operation.

Comment: That's why I was confused by the question - his code is so overly complicated I thought I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Untested JavaScript regex:

```
var myRe = /=(.*)&/igm
var url = 'code=4%2FsAB_thYuaw3b12R0eLklKlc-qcvNg6f8E8pgvu_02MTTJE0NOcyvXkrTQrB3QK8209wSbIpLDEBrk8vUGYKQ41I&scope=https:';
var code = myRe.exec(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\bcode=([^&]+)`. It's sure to grab code query using word boundary 'code=' then capture any characters until it reaches `&` or the end.

test regex here: https://regex101.com/r/eSnB4S/1

Comment: Does the {1,} add anything to just * ?

Comment: @Mark yes. `{1,}` makes sure it matches between **one** and unlimited. `*` can match between **zero** and unlimited. So if you use `*` quantifier instead, and have test case `code=` you will have an empty string in capture group. So having `{1,}` helps prevent that empty string.

Comment: @LuisEstevez well `+` does the same thing `{1,}`. so you can use `+` if you want to match one or more. demo https://regex101.com/r/eSnB4S/2

Comment: @CodeManiac Ahh, yes thanks! I'll use that for now on :)

Comment: I know that, I'm just looking for a real world case where that matters here.  The only difference would be where code=&... my version produces an empty match group and yours produces no match.  But that is also a malformed url with queries so...

Comment: @LuisEstevez always happy to help :) add bit explanation of your regex that will make answer more useful.